# Do I need to verify the email address or domain in Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

If I want to send mail from node through aws SES, what should I verify the mail from where it will be sent or the domain where it is to the node app, if it is the domain that happens if I am in local still in development or if I am going to deploy in an EC2 instance what should I check then?

Answer (score 2):

Generally people tend to whitelist an entire domain as it enables the user to send an email from any email address on that domain to any email address in the world. It also grants more visibility domain wide regarding email health such as bounces and complaints vs an individual sender address.

By whitelisting the domain you can change or add to future applications over sender email addresses.

Also remember that you will want to contact AWS to get out of [SES Sandbox mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) if you don't want to be limited in the functionality.